# MS Access Relationship between 2 tables

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a Access DB and 2 tables

I need to set the relationships but need some help.

table 1

id
name
address
postcode
room-name

table 2

room-names

Then table 2 contains data:

eg:

kitchen, bedroom etc

How do I do this join so that table1 room-name field contains table 2 room-names list?

Comment: Access? We're in 2011 right?? Even Microsoft says to not use it! Use **SQL Compact Edition**, it's more powerful, you don't need to install Access to read it and super small size!

Comment: Is "room-name" in table one a Number?

Comment: @balexandre I hear ya but sometimes we just don't have a choice. My job involves a lot of Access programming. It's a pain but it pays the bills.

Comment: room-name is a field type text

Comment: @balexandre: where does MS say not to use Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a field in table one called "room_name_id" and set it as a Number. It will take up less space in the mdb file over time. (Sidenote: You can't use "name" as a field name since "name" is a reserved word in Access.)

Next create table two so you have an "id" field and a "room_name" field. So if "Spare room" contains id 1 then in table one, room_name_id could be 1.

Here's the SQL that you could use on a query.

```
    SELECT tblInfo.username, tblInfo.address, tblRoomNames.room_name
FROM tblRoomNames INNER JOIN tblInfo ON tblRoomNames.id = tblInfo.room_name_id;
```

This will show something like "Peter", "Narnia", "Spare room" even though table one has "Peter", "Narnia", "1".

P.S. I use this all the time at work to populate dropdown boxes with options for the user to choose from. This way I can update multiple dropdown boxes just by editing one table.

Comment: So table 1's room-name-id is autonumber? and rooms table id is also autonumber?

Comment: No, table 1's room_name_id should be a Number and table 2's id should be autonumber. Or else room_name_id would keep incrementing past the Autonumber being generated in table 2. Bad times. =)

Comment: Also, the more I think about it, table 2's "id" field should probably be named "room_name_id" as well. Access should pick up on this relationship whenever you try to create a new query in design mode. Personal preference.

Comment: I'm getting Relationship Type: One-Too_Many ... is that bad?

Comment: "One Too Many"? or "One To Many"? The relationship you are setting up is a One-To-Many relationship which just means you have "one" field in Table 2 that can belong "to many" entries in Table 1.